# Radius of convergence is 1

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, power-series

Let's assume that $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}$ is convergent conditionally. Then prove that the radius of convergence of $\displaystyle\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}x^{n}$ is equal to $1$

Please explain clearly how to solve this? Thank you so much!

Comment: Let $f(x)=\sum_n a_n x^n$. The point is that if $f(x_0)$ converges, then $f(t)$ converges *absolutely* for $|t|<x_0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since the series converges, we have $\lim a_n=0$. So $|a_n|$ is bounded by, say, $C>0$.

Recall that the radius of convergence $R$ is the largest $R$ such that $\sum a_n x^n$ converges absolutely for all $|x|<R$.

Now 
$$
\sum |a_nx^n|\leq C\sum |x|^n
$$
converges by comparison with the geometric series for all $|x|<1$.

Thus $R\geq 1$.

Now if $R>1$, the series $\sum a_n x^n$ would converge absolutely for all $|x|<R$. In particular for $x=1$. Contradiction with your assumption.

So $R=1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the series converges, $a_n \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$.  Since convergent sequences are bounded, there's a $K$ so that $|a_n| \le K$, for all $n$.  Now the terms $|a_n x^n| \le K|x^n|$, and the series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}K |x^n|$ converges for all $|x| < 1$.  Thus by the comparison test